# Multicharts Stop Loss Not Executing at Specified Level

Tags: multicharts-powerlanguage

I'm developing a trading strategy in MultiCharts using PowerLanguage and have come across a problem where my stop loss is not triggering at the defined level of a 5% loss. Instead, trades are closing with losses greater than this, around 8% or more.

The strategy uses IntrabarOrderGeneration to enable intra-bar order execution. I set the stop loss when entering a long position based on the closing price of the previous bar. However, the trades are not exiting at the 5% loss level as they should according to my SetStopLoss configuration.

Here's the excerpt of the code where I define and set the stop loss:

```
[IntrabarOrderGeneration = true]
// ... [inputs and vars]

// Entry logic
if Close > BbTop and Close > MaValue and MarketPosition <= 0 and canEnterLong then begin
    Buy("Long Entry") next bar at market;
    entryPrice = Close[1]; // Entry price is set based on the closing price of the previous bar
    canEnterLong = false;
    // Set the stop loss and take profit using MultiCharts functions
    SetStopLoss(entryPrice * 0.05); // This should set the stop loss at 5% below the entry price
end;

// ... [other trading logic, if relevant to the problem]

// Exit logic for stop loss and take profit
// [Include here if you have any custom exit logic that might interfere with the stop loss]
```

I have confirmed that slippage and broker settings are not the issue. I'm wondering if there's something in my code causing this, or if it's an issue with how MultiCharts processes the stop loss order.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with stop losses in MultiCharts, or can anyone spot a mistake in my approach?

Comment: Given this is a proprietary language, you're not likely to find much assistance here. Aren't there private forums or paid support by MultiCharts for getting help with this?